# 30 days of displaying the name of the member

Tags: mysql, sql

here is my sql select query:

```
SELECT 
 contact_individual.name,contact_individual.contactID_individual,
 MAX(DATE_FORMAT(payment_individual.expiration,'%m/%d/%Y')) as exp1 
 FROM contact_individual,payment_individual
 WHERE contact_individual.contactID_individual = payment_individual.contactID_individual    
 group by contact_individual.contactID_individual,contact_individual.name
 having MAX(payment_individual.expiration)=DATE_ADD(current_date(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

in this condition, it only displays the name of the member when the date of expiration is 1 month before expiration.
please help me, all I wanted to do is that make it available/or is it possible to display the name of the member for the whole 30 days. 
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
HAVING MAX(payment_individual.expiration) BETWEEN
              NOW()
              AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is great if you had provided some sample data for original and expected results. Could it be that you want to show the memeber whose expiry date is within a month back from today?

```
SELECT 
 contact_individual.name,contact_individual.contactID_individual,
 MAX(DATE_FORMAT(payment_individual.expiration,'%m/%d/%Y')) as exp1 
 FROM contact_individual,payment_individual
 WHERE contact_individual.contactID_individual = payment_individual.contactID_individual    
 group by contact_individual.contactID_individual,contact_individual.name
 having DATE_DIFF(MAX(payment_individual.expiration),Current_Date()) = 30
 ;
```

Comment: no sir. what I wanted to show is the members whose expiry date is going to expire within a month from today.

Comment: How about this? `having DATE_DIFF(MAX(payment_individual.expiration),Current_Date()) = 30` here we assume that max expiry date is greater then the current date to result in positive 30 days as the days difference (literally a month) approx.

Comment: warning:mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\notification.php on line 63